# Laravel testing workbench package: service provider not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I have a package in my workbench which I want to start testing.

Running phpunit in the directory loads the phpunit.xml file and picks up the test class. However it crashes because it can't find my packages service provider.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Appointedd\Appointedd\AppointeddServiceProvider' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/appointedd-microsites/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 158
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="../../../vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Package Test Suite">
            <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

My test class:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class AppointeddTest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

    public function createApplication() {
       $unitTesting = true;
       $testEnvironment = 'testing';
       return require __DIR__.'/../../../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }

    public function testSomething() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Directory structure:

```
/workbend/appointedd/appointedd/
                                src/
                                    Appointedd/Appointedd/
                                                        Appointedd.php
                                                        AppointeddServiceProvider.php
                                                        Facades/
                                                                Appointedd.php
                                tests/
                                    AppointeddTest.php
                                phpunit.xml
```

Comment: hey, any updates on the case?